# Is there a way to remove a standard user's ability to remove/disable extensions in a non-enterprise version of Firefox/Edge?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge

I work for a nonprofit that gives residential clients in substance use disorder treatment access to computers for the purpose of job search/appointment setting/legal issues/research.

We don't allow social media/gambling/gaming/pornography/streaming. I have set plugins up (Cold Turkey) in both Edge (cannot remove/uninstall) and Firefox to block inappropriate websites/apps. I managed mess with the Firefox settings to remove the task bar "extensions" icon (but it still remains an option to disable/remove if you look for it on the drop down). I've had no luck with Edge.

The computers (x4) are running Windows 10 and are not configured in enterprise mode--thus editing permissions uniformly is not an option. The accounts in question are "standard" roles.

I have tried to edit the policies.json files for Firefox (to disable ability to add / remove add-ons) and have not had any success / intended effects are not apparent after browser reboot.

*Please advise!* **I am only moderately tech savvy.** Thank you so much!

What I've done so far:

Tried modifying policies.json files to disallow removal or disabling of extensions in Firefox. --> No apparent effect.

Changed profile settings in Firefox in about:config to remove the puzzle icon for Extensions. --> It worked, but the dropdown menu on the taskbar gives ready access to the add-ons manager still.

Tried setting up parent/child accounts for each PC. --> Did so on one and figured it wasn't worth the hassle because there weren't robust enough features for client web browsers.

Edit 2-15-24: Tried editing the group policy for Microsoft Edge to disallow removal/uninstallation of extension (with 32 character value of the extension in question used). Did not find this to work.

Edit 2-26-24: Elin Lu answered my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensioninstallforcelist) to disallow removal or disabling of extensions in Edge.
And if you cannot configure it with group policy editor, also try to use Windows registry settings.
**Example value:**

```
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallForcelist\1 = "gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp;https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx"
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallForcelist\2 = "abcdefghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnop"
```

**Update：**
Please check for GP path and correct GP name.
You should download and install the Microsoft Edge administrative template firstly, and then add the administrative template to your computer.
1.[Download and install the Microsoft Edge administrative template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge#1-download-and-install-the-microsoft-edge-administrative-template).
2.[Add the administrative template to an individual computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge#add-the-administrative-template-to-an-individual-computer).
You could refer this screenshot find corresponding policy.
[image]
After apply policy you could go to `edge://policy/` check if the policy shows in list, if there is not, you could run **cmd** type `gpupdate /force` to update your policy to see if it works for you.
It doesn’t matter if you are no domain. You can use administrative template or registry settings.
You need note that：For Windows instances not joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain, forced installation is limited to apps and extensions listed in the Microsoft Edge Add-ons website.

Comment: Hi Elin Lu, I am running Windows 10. I went into the local group policy editor and navigated to both User Configuration-->Administrative Templates-->Windows Components-->Microsoft Edge and found "Prevent turning off required extensions" ... I found the appropriate 32 character extension ID for Cold Turkey and input that value and enabled it. I replicated it for the "Computer Configuration" section too just in case. It didn't seem to work. I can still uninstall the Extension. Do I need to be on a non-admin account to see it work?

Comment: HI, I had updated my answer, please help check and if you have any updates, please let us know.

Comment: Hi again Elin, the only path through which I can find Microsoft Edge policy directory is: Local Computer Policy --> Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Microsoft Edge. I don't have a subdirectory named "Policies" under "Computer Configuration" parent.

Comment: Furthermore, the edge://policy/ displays no active policies even though the "Prevent turning off required extensions" policy is set to "Enabled." Why do our directory trees look different?

Comment: For reference, my computers are running Windows 10 Pro, OS Build 19045.4046 and the Edge version is 121.0.2277.128.

Comment: Edit again: Elin, my computers are not connected via a Domain Controller. They are running independently of each other. Does this make GP enforcement impossible if it's local-only?

Comment: Hi Ryan, it doesn’t matter if you are no domain. You can use administrative template or registry settings. I had updated my answer again, please help check it. Regards

Comment: Elin, thank you so much! I figured out what I was doing wrong and placed the .admx / .adml files in the correct places.  You're a life saver~!